# Query timeout expired while running a request from a packaged .NET tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I am working on an application built using a .NET packaged configuration tool. There is a out of box request that in turn fires a delete SQL statement and tries to delete a row from the database. Since past few months, we are receiving the following error- [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Query timeout expired.

We are unable to simulate this scenario in lower environments and can see this issue only on production.

The only issue we think is there might be a deadlock issue in a situation where this delete request is deadlocking with another simultaneous insert in the table (we have a scheduled job that inserts data in a relational database from large XML-splitting data from nodes)

What can be done to resolve this? Note, indexing has been done on the tables recently that reduces the frequency for some time but it again spiked up.

Comment: Is the problem statement ONLY a `DELETE`?  Or is it part of batch of statements within a TRANSACTION?  Or perhaps there's a TRIGGER on the table being DELETED from?  It shouldn't be possible to DEADLOCK a simple DELETE if there is nothing else involved.  It is, however, possible to BLOCK it, while another longer running operation proceeds.  Do you monitor your system for other ongoing queries?  You seem to be using SQL Server, so SQL Server Profiler may help there...

Comment: The problem is these requests firing the SQL statement are hidden from us. Only the base team would know what actually happens behind the scene in the packaged request. I will try to reach out to product base team to get the answer to your first query to begin with! And yes, we are using SQL Server. We had reached out to the DBA earlier, but hadn't received any useful information.

Comment: I wish you luck, without more information you're fighting uphill...  Something happens, but we don't know what, while other things might be happening, but we're not sure and don't know what, etc, etc...

Comment: :( just confirmed-no TRIGGERS, for now I have asked for new time stamps, and fresh PROFILER logs, something better than nothing.